# How to have separate Electron app instances with separate LocalStorage?

Tags: javascript, electron

I have an Electron app and when I start multiple instances of it, they both share the same LocalStorage. Is it possible that multiple instances could have their own separate LocalStorage "domains" (not sure if that's the right word)?

What drives how a particular Electron app knows which LocalStorage domain to use? I thought perhaps it was driven by the file path of the entry point, but I've run separate instances from separate folders and even with distinctly named entry points, and they both still share the same LocalStorage.

I'm relatively new to Electron, so forgive me if there's a really obvious answer here, but if not path, then how do two instances of an electron app running from different paths know that they are indeed two instances of the same app?

Comment: Can't you somehow generate a relatively unique hash when your app instantiate and use it as prefix? The same domain is used because it is the same app you're instantiating (think browser tabs with the same domain url - e.g. stackoverflow.com).

Like this you can write a simple wrapper over LocalStorage API and when setting / getting an item you can auto add/use the hash prefix. You can have a look for example at this [library](https://github.com/ivw/easy-localstorage)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the one hand, it depends on where Electron stores your local storage on disk. This is governed by [app](http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.36.7/api/app/#appgetpathname) module's path for `userData`. If you look it the corresponding folder, you should find a directory called `Local Storage` -- that's where your app saves the data. I guess what you're looking for is to use separate storage for your app depending on whether you run it in production/release or development/test mode; this is easy to achieve by setting the `userData` path when you start your app. For instance, we are using a local folder during development and a tempdir for tests.

Alternatively, take a look at Electron's [session](http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.36.7/api/session/#sessionfrompartitionpartition) module, which you can use to handle multiple session stores.

Comment: This helped me a lot! I imagine I could pass in some command line args to be able to control the userData path. A side issue is that my app thinks its name is 'Electron' (based on app.getName()), so the default userData folder for me (on OSX) is '~Library/Application Support/Electron'. This would be a problem if I had a completely different Electron app, since with such a generic name, both apps would share the same data. The docs say the name should be derived from package.json. I do have it set there and it's not using it. Maybe that's a bug with Electron? Either way, it's a separate issue.

Comment: I think it might use 'productName' instead of 'name'. In any case, you can override it when you start your app, like you say. I'm using command line options which default to NODE_ENV for setting my environments. This works quite well so far to keep release and dev environments separated.

Comment: I tried productName too and it still had me as 'Electron'. Anyways, thanks again for the help!